# Model class not found when running Seeder in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, laravel-artisan, seeding

I am creating an Admin auth to my app and I generated the model with the artisan command:

```
php artisan make:model Admin -m
```

This is the generated class:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Admin extends Model
{
    //
}
```

This created an empty model and a basic migration. I added this lines to the migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 32);
            $table->string('username', 32);
            $table->string('email', 320);
            $table->string('password', 64);            
            $table->string('remember_token', 100)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Then I used the command line to create a seeder:

```
php artisan make:seeder AdminTableSeeder
```

And added the seeder to the `DatabaseSeeder`

```
public function run()
    {
        $this->call(AdminTableSeeder::class);
    }
```

But when I run the seeder `php artisan db:seed` I get a class missing error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Admin' not found in /laravelpath/database/seeds/AdminTableSeeder.php on line 15
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Class 'Admin' not found

It seems to be the Admin model.

I've tried to run the fixes `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` but they didn't help.

Anyone knows what is happening? Why do I get this error and how do I fix it?

**Extra info:** I read somewhere that I should name my app so I executed `php artisan app:name MyAppName` and it added namespaces everywhere (at least in the `Http` folder). I'm not sure if it messed up my classes.

**@edit 1**

This is the AdminTableSeeder

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class AdminTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('admins')->delete();
        Admin::create(array(
            'name'     => 'Victor Ferreira',
            'username' => 'victorferreira',
            'email'    => 'victor.ferreira@live.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('123456'),
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your AdminTableSeeder ?

Comment: @MichalGallovic sure, just did that

Comment: add use MyAppName\Admin; above class definition

Comment: Alright, did what you and @Khan suggested and it works. To be precise I used MyAppName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AdminTableSeeder.php

```
use App\Models\Admin;
```

have a look at your Admin model it is under App\Models namespace that means your Admin model resides under app/Models/ folder. If that doesn't works in case your Admin isn't under app/Models folder then remove Models from your Admin model and make the namespace App\Admin

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked by running this command?

`composer dump-autoload`

You have to run this command to autoload all the new created files.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command before running or executing the seeder file

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```